# Can I set transient properties to fetch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I want to create `NSFetchRequest` and set properties to fetch like this:

```
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"a", @"b", @"c"];
```

where `a` and `b` are stored in Core Data database, and `c` is transient. `executeFetchRequest:` fires an error `Invalid keypath c passed to setPropertiesToFetch:`. But if I uncheck transient-checkbox for property `c` everything will work fine.
So is it really impossible to fetch transient properties or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is really impossible. You can't fetch them because they don't exist in the persistent store - that's what it means to be transient. You can fetch whatever persistent attributes the derived, transient, attribute is created from.